# Avoid numbers in Android layouts?

Tags: android, android-layout

Is it possible to design an Android layout (`LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout`) without specifying any `dp`, `px` or any other units? Maybe using percentages? `layout_weight` is an option. But still what about margins and paddings? Can we completely avoid magic numbers from a layout?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is the [Percent Support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#percent) with its [`PercentFrameLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentFrameLayout.html) and [`PercentRelativeLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html) where you can specify any layout dimensions (i.e. size, position and margins) with percentages instead of absolute values:

```
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent">

     <ImageView
         app:layout_widthPercent="50%"
         app:layout_heightPercent="50%"
         app:layout_marginTopPercent="25%"
         app:layout_marginLeftPercent="25%"/>

</android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Tell me if I am wrong, but I as I know Percent Support Library was released with API23, in pre-lollipop devices is ignored. If I am right, the better idea is still extracting numbers like dimens to xml files like styles.xml.

Comment: @piotrek1543 It was released with the support library v23, but it should support older Android versions too.

Answer (score 3):

You can always define and use `dimension` variable to remove magic number from layouts i.e.:

```
<ImageView 
  layout_width="@dimen/large_photo_size"
  layout_height="@dimen/large_photo_size"
/>
```

Where `@dimen/large_photo_size` is defined inside `dimens.xml` resource file i.e.:

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="large_photo_size">25dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Yet another alternative would be to extract width and height settings into styles i.e.:

```
<style name="Thumbnail">
    <item name="android:layout_width">25dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">25dp</item>
</style>
```

and use it i.e. `<ImageView style="@style/PopupMenu" ... />`

With [themes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#ApplyATheme) you can apply certain styles globally.